# mobile viewport does not open page fit to screen

Tags: html, css, screen, viewport

Problem that bugs me at the moment. Have not found answer so far.

I've got a site with minimum width of 480px applied for devices with screen smaller than 640px;

```
<meta name="viewport" content=" initial-scale=1, width=device-width, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />

<style>
body {margin:0; padding:0;}
@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    .div {width:100%; min-width:480px; background:#ff0000; color:#ffffff;}
}
</style>
```

Thing is, when you open a file on mobile, it does not fit the screen in portrait mode. You need to double click to fit it.

Is there anything could be done so that opens fit to screen on portrait mode?

Thanks guys.

Comment: Do you want to force the user into an orientation?

Comment: No, want to open website fit to screen regardless of device orientation. and min-width of website is 480px..

Comment: Might have to do this via js.  You need something like width = Max(device-width, 480)

Comment: Oh, you want to zoom the page when the screen is too small?

Comment: @bjb568 I guess zoom out as content page is wider then screen. or viewport to become 480px regardless of orientation when device width is less then 640px.

Comment: Have you tried simplifying that meta tag: `<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=0, initial-scale=1.0">`

Comment: For your css selector, did you mean `div` and not `.div`?

Comment: @KaiQing does not work

Comment: @Gohn67 I've got div with class div. :)

Comment: Can you post the url, so I can help you with this issue.

Comment: @user2677350 http://icqz.net/viewport.htm

Answer (score 0):

You have maximum scale and initial scale in your viewport. Change your viewport to : `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Comment: nope, does not automatically fit the page to screen.

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh got ya. Right, below are two links... the 2nd one works keeping the color red - I think that's what your after (code for 2nd link example below, you will need both @medias)! Works on my phone now anyway!

http://www.bootply.com/render/115758

http://www.bootply.com/render/115760

```
            @media (min-width:480px) and (max-width: 640px){
                    .div {
                    width: 100%;
                    background: #ff0000;
                    color: #ffffff;
                    }
            }

            @media (max-width: 640px){
                    .div {
                    background: #ff0000;
                    color: #ffffff;
                    }
            }
```

Comment: nope, does not work either. as you forgot about min-width. it has to be 480px. to check you example, just insert an image and you will see that red box is not 480px wide.